# Azure DevOps hosted agent using wrong typescript version for .njsproj

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

Our `.njsproj` project uses typescript 3.8.2. It's defined in the `package.js` as well as in the `.njsproj` file with `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`.

But the Azure DevOps agent always uses version 4.1 for this project and then the build fails.
For `.csproj` you can just install the appropriate typescript.msbuild nuget package, but how do I set the version for `.njsproj files` to be picked up by the build agent?

Researching this issue gives me lots of different answers from "it's not possible" to "try this solution" which then never worked for the thread starter and for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2019?view=vs-2019#typescript-support):  The Typescript has these method to install.

> The TypeScript NuGet package.

> The TypeScript npm package.

> The TypeScript SDK,

In Azure Devops Agent, it only comes pre-installed Typescript 4.1(Windows-2019). So when you run the pipeline, it will use the version 4.1 by default.

Based on your situation, the method 3 (The TypeScript SDK) could meet your requirement.

You could  download the TypeScript SDK from the website: [Typescript 3.8.2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-382).

Here is the Powershell script example:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile('https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/TypeScriptTeam/vsextensions/typescript-382/3.8.2/vspackage','C:/installer1.exe')

$pathvargs = {C:/installer1.exe /S /v/qn }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs


sleep -s 30
```

**Result:**

[image]

Run the following command to check:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript'  -Recurse -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FullName
```

On the other hand , you could directly download the exe file from the website and  upload it to your repo. Then you could directly run the following command to install it.

```
$pathvargs = {$(build.sourcesdirectory)/TypeScript_SDK.exe /S /v/qn }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $pathvargs


sleep -s 30
```

Comment: @MuhKuh. You can also try to create and use the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to run the pipeline.